# Recycler View Clicked States when using Picasso for android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso, statelistdrawable

I have created a recyclerview with a GridLayoutManager. Each item in the recyclerview is an imageview wrapped in a relativelayout. I want to have a clicked effect on this imageview, sort of a tint effect. I have used Picasso to load images into the imageviews. I have even implemented multi-select using the link below.
https://github.com/ismoli/DynamicRecyclerView. 
   So far I have tried setting the background of the image in xml using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/tint" android:state_activated="true" />
<item android:drawable="@color/tint" android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

However, this does not work(maybe because I'm setting an image to the imageview using Picasso).

```
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(imageData.get(i).getImageFilePath())).resize(300, 300)
            .into(viewHolder.resultImage);
```

How do I have a clicked state(tint effect) on the recyclerview item while using Picasso?

Comment: Do you want the state on the background of the item or on the imageview?

Comment: I've tried to set it to both the parent layout as well as the image view. I succeeded in getting a different image for the pressed state, i.e android:state_pressed="true", however, I need a different image set to the recyclerview item on long press. The long press triggers contextual action mode, and I can select multiple items. This multi-select sate is where I need a different background to show that a certain item is selected.

Comment: I managed one part of the problem I wrapped the imageview in a framelayout. Set the framelayout attributes - android:clickable="true",android:focusable="true",      android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground".

Comment: The second part requires me to highlight the selected items in multi-select mode(contextual action mode). Currently wondering if I need to toggle states of the view in contextual action mode, in order to get a "selected item" look(highlighted in some way).